# Did Quarkus 2.7.1.Final remove support for annotations?

Tags: quarkus

Did Quarkus 2.7.1.Final remove support for annotations? Following code does not work, but worked in Quarkus 1.11. Code below.

Any suggestions/pointers are appreciated.
Thanks

GreetingResource.java:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        if (isGramMessageHandlerFound()){
            return "Hello - GramMessageHandler method found!";
        } else {
            return "Sorry - no GramMessageHandler method found!";
        }
    }

    @GramMessageHandler(type="firstGramMessageHandler")
    void firstGramMessageHandler()
    {
    }

    @GramMessageHandler(type="secondGramMessageHandler")
    void secondGramMessageHandler()
    {
    }

    boolean isGramMessageHandlerFound()
    {
        final Method[] methods = getClass().getMethods();
        for (final Method method : methods) {
            final GramMessageHandler gramMessageHandler = method.getAnnotation(GramMessageHandler.class);
            if (gramMessageHandler != null){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the annotation:
GramMessageHandler.java:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GramMessageHandler
{
   String type() default "java.lang.String";
}
```

GreetingResourceTest.java

```
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

@QuarkusTest
public class GreetingResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void testHelloEndpoint() {
        given()
          .when().get("/hello")
          .then()
             .statusCode(200)
             .body(is("Hello - GramMessageHandler method found!"));
    }
}
```

Running `mvn clean test` results in:

```
[ERROR]   GreetingResourceTest.testHelloEndpoint:18 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: is "Hello - GramMessageHandler method found!"
  Actual: Sorry - no GramMessageHandler method found!
```

Comment: The problem goes away if you use `quarkus.arc.dev-mode.monitoring-enabled=false`

Comment: yes that worked. thanks @geoand

Please share how you figured it out or if there is a way to figure that out. It was not in the Release Notes or in the list of configuration options. Surprised the behavior changed with newer Quarkus Release. Thanks again.

Comment: The setting above, when true leads to the creation of a subclass of your class. That subclass does not contain the annotations.